# How is this not a link-only answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, moderation, flagging, accepted-answer

I flagged [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/3494/47855) answer as NAA. The answer seems like a classic ["your answer is in another castle"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) answer. The question asked about whether a certain country was safe and whether there was anything that could be done to stay safe, and the answer essentially said "here are three webpages to read".

My flag was declined with the message:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

How is this answer not NAA? I do realize that it was posted by a ♦ mod, but mods are not above the system (if anything, they should be paragons of good behavior), and also realize that the answer was upvoted and accepted, but then neither of those things [redeem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209144/highly-upvoted-and-accepted-link-only-answer) a post either.

Comment: One aspect to consider is that this is a very old post (as a matter of fact 4 years older than the meta post you link to refers to), so standards on this site probably evolved over this time.

Comment: Oh hey, that's my answer! Sorry you didn't like it, but it was in the early days of the site before we had ironed out exactly what we wanted in a website.  However, if you feel you can improve it, I welcome it! Thanks for noticing.

Comment: @Robert realised his question kinda had two parts as well (also something we don't usually have these days), so I've added my experience of Cuba to it - as I visited it two years ago :)

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it's one of our best answers on the site by any stretch, but it's somewhat more than just the bare links given as examples in "your answer is in another castle." It is, at least, a collection of three relevant resources to help answer the question, with a brief description for each.

The answer is also six years old (indeed, it predates "your answer is in another castle" by a few years), and site norms and standards have evolved since then. Updating and improving answers to out-of-date questions is a valuable activity. I don't think scrubbing the site of content that doesn't completely meet our current editorial standards is, especially if it will result in removing information. You flagged the question as "Not An Answer," but it is an answer, just not a fantastic one.

Finally, I'm a big proponent of improving useful content rather than deleting it. Some things just need to be deleted, because there's little or nothing of value there, but that's not the case of this answer. Instead of flagging it for deletion, perhaps it would make more sense to edit in an excerpt or two from the quoted links and make it a better answer?

Comment: Yes I think editing in the details, or asking the original author to do so, is likely the right way to go about improving old post quality. Whenever possible.